# How to hide the labels of graphs that are not toggled in ChartJS

Tags: callback, chart.js

I am displaying price data on a chart but with two different timescales.

The problem is that when I toggle the shorter graph, it shows the labels of the longer time scale one still.

[Image of both lines showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wxGE.png)

[Image of problem line showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJpLZ.png)

Code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('priceChart').getContext('2d');
var priceChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
    datasets: [

        {
            label: 'Price150s',
            data: [
                [{
                        "x": "20:32:39",
                        "y": 4325.04
                    },
                    {
                        "x": "20:32:42",
                        "y": 4324.91
                    },
                    {
                        "x": "20:32:45",
                        "y": 4325.17
                    },
                    {
                        "x": "20:32:48",
                        "y": 4325.02
                    }
                ]
            ],
            tension: 0.2,
            borderColor: 'rgb(231,62,62)'
        },

        {
            label: 'Price25m',
            data: [
                [{
                        "x": "20:32:39",
                        "y": 4325.04
                    },
                    {
                        "x": "20:32:42",
                        "y": 4324.91
                    },
                    {
                        "x": "20:32:45",
                        "y": 4325.17
                    },
                    {
                        "x": "20:32:48",
                        "y": 4325.02
                    }
                ]
            ],
            tension: 0.2,
            borderColor: 'rgb(231,62,62)'
        }
    ]
},
options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
        display: false,
    },
    scales: {
        y: {
            beginAtZero: false
        }
    }
}
});
```

I understand that you can add some sort of callback on a click or something to hide the details but I couldn't find anything specific for when you are using dictionaries for the x labels.
Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to a time scale will solve this issue in the easyest way because then this is the default behaviour as you can see in the example below:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [{
            x: new Date('10-16-2021'),
            y: 1
          }, {
            x: new Date('10-18-2021'),
            y: 4
          }, {
            x: new Date('10-19-2021'),
            y: 8
          },
          {
            x: new Date('10-20-2021'),
            y: 6
          }
        ],
        borderColor: 'pink',
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [{
            x: new Date('10-18-2021'),
            y: 3
          }, {
            x: new Date('10-19-2021'),
            y: 9
          },
          {
            x: new Date('10-20-2021'),
            y: 4
          }
        ],
        borderColor: 'orange',
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time'
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
```